# Enter Email Address to HTML form, then a Submit button opens the email client with address entered

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to create a form that the user can type in an email address and then when I click the submit button, Outlook (or the user's email client) opens an email to the address from the form. Here is my code:

```html
<p>Enter the Email Address of the advisor you which to message.</p>
<!-- Display body section. -->
<form action="mailto:'email'">

<p>Email: <input type="text" name="email" size="10"> </p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Email"></p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Attach an `eventlistener` for submit action.

Get the value you entered in `input` field and use

```
window.open('mailto:'+email);
```

Here is complete snippet.

```js
document.getElementById("form").addEventListener("submit", function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
   window.open('mailto:'+email);
   

})
```

```html
<p>Enter the Email Address of the advisor you which to message.</p>
<!-- Display body section. -->
<form id="form">

<p>Email: <input id="email" type="text" name="email" size="10"> </p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Email"></p>
</form>
```

This will open user's email client. Ofcourse you should not expect this function to send emails

Comment: I am putting this form and submit button inside of a PHP document. how do I add the document.getElementByID inside the PHP?

Comment: put it in scrip tags

Comment: What am I still doing wrong?

<script>
document.getElementById("form").addEventListener("submit", function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
   window.open('mailto:'+email);

})
</script>
<p>Enter the Email Address of the advisor you which to message.</p>
<!-- Display body section. -->
<form id="form">

<p>Email: <input id="email" type="text" name="email" size="10"> </p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Email"></p>
</form>

Comment: @Luca I don't know where to put the script tags. If I put </script> under the </form> I get an error

Comment: nonono, put everything from <script> to </script> below everything you can see on the screen (last element of the body)

Comment: @Luca got it! Thank you!!

Comment: @Luca thanks for helping the guy. I was doing somethin else :)